# Read and Write Image Block into DDR using Vivado IP Block

Tags: image-processing, vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

We are working on project where we need to do some image processing on FPGA. For that purpose we are using ZedBoard with linaro (Ubuntu Version) running on it. 
What we have already done is we have stored the image in binary form pixel by pixel in DDR using python script on Processing System of Zedboard.

Now our task is to read the content of DDR memory, process it and send back the processed output to DDR Memory again. We are using vivado xilinx tool for FPGA part. We tried to use AXI-DMA with AXI-Interconnect to read and write data from DDR. 
My question is, Do We need to use SDK and some sort of C coding to read and write DDR Memory on Programmable Logic side? As we want to make our module start reading the data from DDR with a control signal and then start actual processing of Image data. Once we read specific block of data, process it and store the result back to DDR memory on the fly. We are not sure which IP Block do we need in our block design for vivado. Also do we need Block Ram Memory at the end before sending the date to DDR.

Can anyone who already done this sort of project or have any knowledge ? Any help from your side will be appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: Your story is missing **a lot** of vital implementation information, so it is difficult to answer your question. However: it is possible to use AXI-DMA without SDK/C. C or C++ would indicate you would use a soft-core CPU in your logic, which is not required. Instead you could make a state-machine in HDL. At least: that all depends on what you want/your requirements. Read the user guide of the AXI-DMA core on how to use it. And just google ["tutorial axi dma"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=tutorial+axi+dma)

Comment: Actually what we need to do is , we have Zed board which we need to boot from SD card having linaro in it. We need to read data from DDR Memory and write back to DDR memory. AXI DMA with AXI interconnect will do the task of hardware design but I need to use DMA controller using ARM Processor of Zed board.

Comment: You are saying contradicting things. You first say that you are running Linaro on your ARM core, which is an OS that has build in memory control. And next you say you want to use that same ARM core for some bare metal application with AXI DMA. Very unclear.

Comment: I am sorry If my statements look like contracditing but I mean the same as my first statement. I am running Zedboard with linaro operating system. What I need to do is to control DDR read and write using DMA controller. As  I need to write code in SDK to control it but also I need to add AXI DMA driver for linux as well as I need to add its entry inside device tree blob.

Comment: try to have a look here: https://github.com/Digilent.
I have some example about this and the git repository of Digilent was my starting point!

Comment: However, YES, you mast use a VDMA (Video DMA) and an SDK to set it, start the streaming and so on

Answer (score 0):

The zynq FPGA provide an AMBA AXI interconnect for that purpose.

[image: Zynq FPGA overview]

This is the interconnect on the right.